# How to modify this code for this requirement to copy data from one excel book to another until last cell?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I modify this code to meet this requirement:
- to copy data from one excel book to another until last cell?

**Code Below:**

```vb
    Sub Copy_Over()
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim b As Integer
        Dim LastRow As Long
        Dim Lastrow2 As Long

        Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
        For i = 1 To 1
            LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Lastrow2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row + 1

            For b = 1 To LastRow
                Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Lastrow2, i).Value = Cells(b, i).Value
                Lastrow2 = Lastrow2 + 1
            Next
        Next
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Just takes one line of code to do the Copy of the entire row.

```
Option Explicit  ' always add this
Sub Copy_Over()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim nRow1 As Integer
    Dim LastRow1 As Long    ' use suffix, as 1/2 or From/To
    Dim LastRow2 As Long

    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    LastRow1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastRow2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For nRow1 = 1 To LastRow1

        Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(LastRow2 + nRow1).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(nRow1).Value

    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason to loop one row at a time.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyOver()
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' Uncomment when code is working.

    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheet = Application.Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim destinationSheet As Worksheet
    Set destinationSheet = Application.Workbooks("Book2.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Dim lastRowOnSourceSheet As Long
    lastRowOnSourceSheet = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim lastRowOnDestinationSheet As Long
    lastRowOnDestinationSheet = destinationSheet.Cells(destinationSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    If (lastRowOnDestinationSheet + 1 + lastRowOnSourceSheet) > destinationSheet.Rows.Count Then
        MsgBox "There aren't enough rows in '" & destinationSheet.Name & "'. Nothing has been copy-pasted. Code will stop running now."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    sourceSheet.Rows("1:" & lastRowOnSourceSheet).Copy
    destinationSheet.Cells(lastRowOnDestinationSheet + 1, "A").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True ' Uncomment when code is working.
End Sub
```

You could also skip the clipboard and assign the value from one range to the another range directly.

Comment: It says subscript out of range  i did modify  source sheet  and destination sheet to book1.xlsx and book2.xlsx.

Comment: @SantoshKumarReddyBadugula, you changed `Set sourceSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")` to `Set sourceSheet = Worksheets("Book1.xlsx")`? That's wrong and you will get an error (if that's what you did). You should put the name of the sheet between the brackets, not the name of the workbook.

Comment: I need to go with diffrent workbooks how that works?

Comment: @SantoshKumarReddyBadugula, have edited my post/code to use different workbooks.

Comment: its stopping at   Set destinationSheet = Application.Workbooks("Book2.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1") (changed to sheet1) and prompting me out same error subscript out of range.

Comment: @SantoshKumarReddyBadugula, check that `Book2` has file extension `.xlsx` and contains a sheet called `"Sheet1"`. Also, is `Book2` already open before you run the code? If not, either you need to open it before running the code -- or you need to provide the full path to the workbook (not just its name). So that Excel can find locate the file.

Comment: How can i modify this code to copy over random columns say i need to copy column A ,c,d and e and paste in another workbook as column a,b,c,d?

Comment: Can you help me on above comment , and paste another work book data in the same process from  last filled cell. @chillin